# random variables and their maximum expected value

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

I read a statement in a book and I can't realize what exactly it means, and why it is true.

> a set of random variables are given. in general, the expected value of the maximum of random variables is *not* equal to the maximum of the expected  values of these variables.

I would like to know what exactly it means and why it is true.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two independent coins $c_1,c_2$ which have equal probability of heads or tails.

Assign a value of $1$ for a head and $0$ for a tail.

Then $E c_1 = E c_2 = {1 \over 2}$ and $\max (E c_1, E c_2) = {1 \over 2}$.

Now consider $\max(c_1,c_2)$, that is, toss both coins and take the 'best' result. Then $E [\max(c_1,c_2)] = {3 \over 4}$ (just look at all 4 possibilities).

Hence $\max (E c_1, E c_2) \neq E [\max(c_1,c_2)]$.

**Addendum**:
Note that in the first case, heads and tails are equally likely so
$E c_1 = {1 \over 2} 0 + {1 \over 2} 1 = {1 \over 2}$.

In the second case, each pair of possibilities is equally likely so
\begin{eqnarray}
E [\max(c_1,c_2) &=& {1 \over4} \max(0,0) + {1 \over4} \max(0,1) +{1 \over4} \max(1,0) +{1 \over4} \max(1,1)\\
&=& {1 \over4} 0 + {1 \over4} 1 +{1 \over4} 1 +{1 \over4} 1 \\
&=& {3 \over 4}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Excuse me if my question is very obvious, it has been 9 years I didn't study statistics. $E[max(c_1,c_2)]$ equals to the expectation of `head` for both coins, right? then it should be $$x_1 \times P(x_1) + x_2 \times P(x_2) = 1/2 \times1+1/2\times1=1 $$
then why it is $3/4$?

Comment: No. It is the expected value of the $\max$. The possible values for $(c_1,c_2)$ are $(0,0), (0,1),(1,0), (1,1)$ and the corresponding $\max$ are $0,1,1,1$ hence the expected value is ${3 \over 4}$.

Comment: Note that $\max$ takes the 'best' result. If you toss two coins then intuitively the chances of getting **at least one** head must be greater than getting a head with a single toss.

Comment: `best` result occurs when the result of tossing both coins be `head`, am I right?

Comment: It depends in how you measure 'best'. If you value the result with $\max(c_1,c_2)$ then there are 3 (out of 4) 'best' results, that is any pair with at least one head.

Comment: If so then $$3/4 = (0\times1/4) + (1\times1/4) + (1\times1/4) + (1\times1/4)$$ the $1$ is because the occurrence of $(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ are included in our `best` and the $0$ is because $(0,0)$ is not one of the bests. right?

Comment: Yes, I added something to that effect in the answer. Be careful though, you are looking at the expectation over **all** possibilities, not just a restricted expectation over a subset of 'best possibilities'.

Comment: thanks a lot. It was very helpful :)